# How to lazy load 3rd party videos (fed via javascript)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, lazy-loading

I'm building this site that has 17 modals and majority of the modals have a few medical videos that are being fed by a 3rd party company (view medica) via javascript. This is causing the page to take a longer time to load.

I was wondering if they are ways to lazy load the videos to help improve the loading speed.

An example of the 3rd party video feed:

```
                <!-- ViewMedica Embed Start -->
            <div id="A_0fd328f1"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://viewmedica.com/js/vm.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">client="1202"; openthis="A_0fd328f1"; width=720; vm_open()</script>
            <!-- ViewMedica Embed End -->
```

The website is being built on Bootstrap 4. I don't know if the client would be okay with me posting their website on here but if there is anything I can do to help solve this please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: well does the video player allow it? That is the limiting factor.

Comment: I found a javascript called b-lazy (which is really easy to use). It seems like the page is loading faster but that could be an assumption. I have to find a way to test it out. Chrome dev tool has a performance but it's acting funny. I'm thinking using 3rd party sites that test web page speed to see if they give a different rating. I think google page speed test only does it for the entire website. I'll update this if I find anything but until then if anybody has any inputs please share it :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like everything runs smoothly and that the lazy load is working (even though I have been looking for a tool that officially tells you that there is lazy load is working) but the site works. Page loads. You can scroll through everything and then the videos start loading up one by one and there is no page jumping or anything.

The easiest way I have found to add lazy loading is blazy.js
https://github.com/dinbror/blazy#demo

Why I used blazy.js:

- It is lightweight, less than 1.4KB and less than 1.25KB if you don't need IE7- support.
- it's very easy to use (you just link the javascript in your html and then use the class b-lazy for anything you want to lazy load).

This thing is perfect and hopefully it helps someone else out.